# Swapping characters using TRegEx in Delphi

Tags: regex, delphi

I need to swap character dot with comma and vice versa simultaneously.

```
function TformMain.SwapString(input, fromSymbol, toSymbol: String): String;
begin
  Result := AnsiReplaceStr(input, fromSymbol, '_');  //100,200_00
  Result := AnsiReplaceStr(Result, toSymbol, fromSymbol); //100.200_00
  Result := AnsiReplaceStr(Result, '_', toSymbol); //100.200,00
end;
```

How to do this using TRegEx in Delphi Rio?

Comment: Just follow [this doc](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/Rio/en/TRegExReplace_(Delphi)).

Comment: Regarding your sample code: what if the string contains the `_` character?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although this is not an answer to your question (how to do this using regular expressions), I'd like to point out that this task can be performed with much greater runtime performance using a simple loop:

```
function SwapPeriodComma(const S: string): string;
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  Result := S;
  for i := 1 to S.Length do
    case S[i] of
      '.':
        Result[i] := ',';
      ',':
        Result[i] := '.';
    end;
end;
```

This is much faster than both the `AnsiReplaceStr` approach and the regular expression approach.

Generalised to any two characters:

```
function SwapChars(const S: string; C1, C2: Char): string;
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  Result := S;
  for i := 1 to S.Length do
    if S[i] = C1 then
      Result[i] := C2
    else if S[i] = C2 then
      Result[i] := C1;
end;
```

(If you are OK with a procedure instead of a function, you can do this in-place and save memory and gain speed. But most likely you don't need such optimisations.)

Comment: Yes, I agree it is much faster. I am learning the regular expression, and I thought it would give a better performance. For the sake of learning, how to it in Regex?